# How to get like/share/1+ counts for a page using ruby?

Tags: ruby

How would you get facebook like, twitter share and google 1+ counts?

For [example](http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/31/5051682/googles-next-generation-nexus-5-android-4-4-kitkat-and-more) currently has 78 likes, 158 tweets, and 21 1+.

I tried nokogiri to scrape the source of the page, but the problem is that these things get loaded after the page loads.

Any idea how I could get the counts for these shares using ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use library that can handle Javascript.

For example, following is a solution that use [selenium-webdriver](http://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver):

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

url = 'http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/31/5051682/' + 
      'googles-next-generation-nexus-5-android-4-4-kitkat-and-more'

frame_count_selectors = [
  ['likes', '.fb_iframe_widget iframe', '.pluginCountTextDisconnected'],
  ['tweets', 'iframe.twitter-tweet-button', '#count'],
  ['+1s', '#___plusone_0 iframe', '#aggregateCount'],
]

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox # :chrome / :phantomjs / ...
driver.get(url)
frame_count_selectors.each do |name, frame_sel, count_sel|
  driver.switch_to.default_content
  frame = driver.find_element(:css, frame_sel)
  driver.switch_to.frame frame
  count = driver.find_element(:css, count_sel).text
  puts "#{count} #{name}"
end
driver.quit
```

output example:

```
82 likes
160 tweets
21 +1s
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this solution out in the evening. If I am going to run this Ruby code on AWS or Heroku, I cannot use `: firefox` though right? Should I go with `:phantomjs` in that situation?

Comment: @JasonKim, Yes, `phantomjs` does not require you screen. But you should install [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).